# Django View to return template with refreshed modal window

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django

I'm using Django form in modal window where core content (in  container) generated by JS. On submit django model instance saved without any issues `if form.is_valid() == True` a modal window closes with switching focus on current background page.
However `if form.is_valid() == False` the modal content just opens in separate URL instead and takes all browser screen as View renders just a short code fragment in .html file.

The goal is to refresh the modal window on current condition in case `if form_is_valid() == False` with form errors.

Template `"accounts/profile_settings.html"` contains a form and submit button which renders inside

```
<div class="preferences_content">
    {% comment %} JS generated dynamic content depends on tab pressed. {% endcomment %}
</div>
```

My JS knowldge is very basic so I appreciate any suggestion on this topic.

**The View :**

```
def profile_update_view(request):
    """ Updates current Profile instance."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        current_profile = request.user.profile
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=current_profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', "/"))
        else:
            profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm()
            return render(request, "accounts/profile_settings.html", {'profile_form': profile_form})
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm()
        return render(request, "accounts/profile_settings.html", {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var openModalLink = document.getElementById("openPreferencesModal");
    var modal = document.getElementById("preferencesModal");
    var span = modal.querySelector(".close");
    var preferencesContent = modal.querySelector(".preferences_content");
    var tabs = modal.querySelectorAll(".tab");

    openModalLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        modal.style.display = "block"; // Встановлюємо стиль блоку при відкритті модального вікна

        tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
            tab.classList.remove('active');
        });

        tabs[0].classList.add('active');

        // Отримуємо url першої вкладки та завантажуємо вміст
        var firstTabUrl = tabs[0].getAttribute("data-url");
        fetch(firstTabUrl)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                preferencesContent.innerHTML = data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching content:', error);
            });
    });

    span.addEventListener("click", function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    });

    window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target === modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    });

    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        tab.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
                tab.classList.remove('active');
            });

            tab.classList.add('active');

            var url = tab.getAttribute("data-url");
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    preferencesContent.innerHTML = data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching content:', error);
                });
        });
    });

    var editLink = modal.querySelector(".base_info a[href='']");
    editLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
            if (tab.getAttribute("href") === "#profile") {
                tab.click();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="preferencesModal" class="preferences_modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="preferences_modal_content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <section class="profile_info">

            {% if user.profile.avatar %}
              <img src={{ user.profile.avatar.url }} alt="avatar">
            {% else %}
              <img src={% static "img/default_profile_avatar.svg" %} alt="avatar">
            {% endif %}
            
            <div class="base_info">
              <span>{{ user.profile.username }}</span>
              <span>{{ user.email }}</span>
              {% if user.profile.first_name and user.profile.last_name %}
                <span>{{ user.profile.first_name}}, {{user.profile.last_name}}</span>
              {% endif %}
              <a href="">Edit</a>
            </div>

        </section>

        <section class="preferences_data">
            <div class="preferences_tabs">
                {% comment %} Tabs {% endcomment %}
                <a href="#preferences" class="tab" data-url="{% url 'preferences:preferences_update' %}">Preferences</a>
                <a href="#profile" class="tab" data-url="{% url 'accounts:profile_update' %}">Profile</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="preferences_content">
              {% comment %} JS generated dynamic content depends on tab pressed. {% endcomment %}
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```